# numpy follow a self-indexing list without loops

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list `[A,B,C,D,E]` and a list of indexes `[3,2,0,4,1]` but the indexes actually points to itself, giving the order to follow.

So starting at 0, next index is 3, then at index 3, the next index is 4,1,2,0 etc.

I can achieve this by looping and updating the index, but my list may have thousands of points, Is there a way to avoid loops and vectorize this?

my code:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(['A','B','C','D','E'])
idxs = np.array([3,2,0,4,1])
indexes = []
i = 0
for _ in range(len(idxs)):
    i = idxs[i]
    indexes.append(i)
print(indexes)
print(arr[indexes])
```

output:

```
[3, 4, 1, 2, 0]
[D, E, B, C, A]
```

Comment: This process is iterative in essence so I don't see how it can be vectorized...

Comment: @Julien in which case, the answer is probably just "use `numba`" if this is truly performance critical. 1000's is actually very small, so unless you are doing this operations *many many times* then it's probably fine as is

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yea tbh its not big enough to require numba. I was hoping for some numpy indexing wizardry that i wasnt aware of

Comment: Hmmm if `numpy` has something like `arr.getitem.accumlate` this could be pushed down into the numpy layer. Note, ufuncs provide this usually, e.g `arr.add.accumulate` but yeah don't think there is any way to do it with indexing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do looks to me like a depth first search in the graph where each node is a number from `0` to `n-1` (n = 5 in your example) with a single outgoing edge to the next index it points to. The python solution is already pretty efficient, but if you want something pre-made I think scipy has the solution:

```
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import depth_first_order
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
import numpy as np

idx = np.asarray([3,2,0,4,1])
data = np.ones(5)
row = np.arange(5)
sparse_graph = csr_matrix((data, (row, idx)), shape=(5, 5))
depth_first_order(sparse_graph, 0)[0]
# Outputs: array([0, 3, 4, 1, 2], dtype=int32)
arr = np.array(['A','B','C','D','E'])
arr[depth_first_order(sparse_graph, 0)[0]]
# Outputs: array(['A', 'D', 'E', 'B', 'C'], dtype='<U1')
```

If you want to start from the first value, instead of the 0-th, replace by

```
depth_first_order(sparse_graph, idx[0])[0]
```

Comment: works great and order of magnitude faster for larger lists